# Two implicitly specified distinct subjects in a single sentence

Tags: grammar

Consider the following sentences.

> A: **私は**相手に安過ぎる質が低い物をあげれば、**相手は**怒る可能性がある。

Is it natural and understandable if I remove the subjects as follows?

> B: 相手に安過ぎる質が低い物をあげれば、怒る可能性がある。

Comment: The first sentence is simply a grammatical error. The subject in a conditional clause is never marked with は (except the one that means "at least" combined with words that stand for number or amount).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's even preferred form (if you do add 私が, then the listener might think there is an emphasis there - as in `If *I* give...`)

Apart from that, I would correct your sentences as follows:

> A: 私が相手に、安過ぎる、質が低い物をあげれば、相手は怒る可能性がある。
>
> B: 相手に、安過ぎる、質が低い物をあげれば、怒る可能性がある。

This is because 安過ぎる質が低い物 would be considered hard to read and it's customary to add 句読点 in this sort of cases.